# Locally nilpotent groups (III)

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that if $G$ is nilpotent than $T$ (the torsion-subgroup of $G$) is direct product of p-subgroups.
What if $G$ is locally nilpotent? How can we extend the result to this case?